# VB.NET Error : "The source of the report definition has not been specified." on Report Viewer Parameter Setting

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, reportviewer

By VS2012 i connect to the reporting webservice and need to load the "handShake" Parameter into my report which is a ServerReport, not a LocalReport.

This is my Page_Init Code :

```
    If (Request.QueryString("handShake") = Nothing) Then
        Response.Redirect("~/AccessDenial.aspx")
    End If

    '' Set up the credentials
    ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = New Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("MyReportServerPath"))
    ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = New MyReportServerCredentials()

    Dim objparameter As Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportParameter

    objparameter = New Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportParameter("handShake", Request.QueryString("handShake").ToString)

    ReportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters(objparameter)
```

The last line of code gives me the Error :

```
         The source of the report definition has not been specified."
```

On lots of Forums they say I need to change serverReport to localReport but this is not the case...

Lots of Thanks for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to

```
.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl
```

and

```
.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials
```

you also have to specify

```
.ServerReport.ReportPath
```

that points to actual report in SSRS. This is report definition (ordinary an uploaded RDL) that you set the parameters for. E.g.

```
ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/My Reports/Summary Report"
```

Comment: Thanks, i already had that code only somewhere in a wrong place ... :/ Thank you very much